# How to create proxy if you have more than one interface using ClientBase<T>?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a service hosted that have two interface A and B. I'm trying to implement proxy class for my client by using ClientBase. However, I don't know how to declare it.

This is what I thought it should be:

```
public class ServiceProxy : ClientBase<IA>, ClientBase<IB>, IA, IB
{
.......
}
```

Is that the right way to declare it ? If not, what would be the correct way ? Thank you.

Comment: Multiple Inheritance isn't allowed in C#

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz: I thought this is about interface, and not inheritance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to overcome the multiple inheritance problem, via composition by keeping an instance of each as a private property, and implementing interface methods/properties to access the private instances.  (Can't be sure this will work for you in this case depending on what kind of factories are instantiating your service proxies.)  In this case I'm guessing IA and IB might have some methods with identical signatures, in which case you will need to use explicit interface implementations to avoid conflicts.

```
public class ServiceProxy : IA, IB
{
    private ClientBase<IA> IAProxy {get;set;}
    private ClientBase<IB> IBProxy {get;set;}    


    public void IA.SomeInterfaceMethod(){   
      IAProxy.SomeInterfaceMethod();
    }

    public void IB.SomeInterfaceMethod(){   
      IBProxy.SomeInterfaceMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: @HoangMinh Great, note when calling these methods, since they are explicite interface implementations, you have to cast the ServiceProxy to the interface type so it knows which you want to call `IA iaProxy = (new ServiceProxy()) as IA;` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to inherit from two base classes in C#.

What you can do instead is to use composition to create a class that implements both interfaces and delegates implementation to two instance members: `ClientBase<IA>` and `ClientBase<IB>`

But once you do that you have to ask yourself why would you do that. Why can't you just use both proxys separately from each other. The only reason I can come up with is if your applying the [Façade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

Comment: From what I understand is that I need to create an interface C that will have the interface of A and B, and use it for the ClientBase<T> class, which would be ClientBase<IC>. Is that correct ?